# uwp: desktop app, using "not allowed" APIs for app that will NOT be deployed via MS store. Does it work?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a Windows desktop app, and I have a set of p/invoke APIs that I need to use, such as

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool GlobalMemoryStatusEx([In, Out] MEMORYSTATUSEX lpBuffer);
```

I know this will fail certifications for MS store, but I don't care, since I do my own deployment. Having said that, the APIs work correctly in both Debug and Release.

**Is there any issues I should be aware of - can this fail on my customer's machine?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is not recommended, generally speaking, if you don't want to upload the package to the Store, this will work.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I do understand it's not recommended. But assuming I don't upload to store, and this is just a Windows desktop app, x64 only, I should be fine, yes?

Comment: Yes, you could do it if you don't like to upload your app to the store. The store has more security concerns, so it has more requirements.

Comment: FYI this is not related to security; the Store API Checks are not a security mechanism but a supportability mechanism.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT you mean, supported by all WinRT platforms? Assuming my needs are x64 Desktop only , is Roy Li's answer still correct? Namely, I can safely do the above.

Comment: Yes,you can do it. I'm pretty sure `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` is allowed in the Store anyway.